# Is it possible to use multiple input settings for an indicator on different timeframes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm looking to see if you can change an indicators INPUT settings based on what timeframe you are looking at.

For an example, the SuperTrend indicator has 3 different input settings; ATR Period(10), Source(hl2) and ATR Multiplier(3). Is it possible to have on the 1 HOUR timeframe all these settings, but when you change to the DAILY timeframe the ATR Multiplier changes from 3 to 1.5

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using hard coded multiplier while calling the supertrend, you can calculate the required value in a variable and pass it to the indicator. Example below

```
multiplier = timeframe.period == '60' ? 3 : timeframe.period == 'D' ? 1.5 : 3
```

Here, if the period is 60 min (1Hour) then multipler will be 3 , else if period is Day then multipler will be 1.5 and in rest all cases will be 3. you can use this multiplier variable as input to any indicator call in pinescript.